# Disable qDebug output locally with a macro

Tags: c++, qt, macros, qt5, qdebug

I used qDebug all over the code. Now I would like to limit its output by translation units, defining a separate macro to enable/disable qDebug output in a translation unit:

test.pro:

```
DEFINES += NO_DEBUG_ONE
```

testone.cpp:

```
#ifdef NO_DEBUG_ONE
#define QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT
#endif
```

testtwo.cpp:

```
#ifdef NO_DEBUG_TWO
#define QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT
#endif
```

So, setting macros like this I expected to get qDebug output only in testtwo.cpp, but I see the qDebug messages from both translation units.

What am I missing here and how to solve it?

Comment: Are you setting those defines before including *any* Qt header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your code to the top of `testone.cpp` and `testtwo.cpp` and you should be good to go.

You can use `QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT` and `QT_NO_WARNING_OUTPUT` when you compile your app but those must be set before the Qt headers are included.

Using cmake you could add those defines on a per-file base but I don't see a simple way doing that with qmake.

Comment: Thank you, I finally found time to test it and it works as expected!

Answer (score 0):

As it's a QMake macro I don't think you can do it locally. the only way is to use a standard macro as `-D TEST` and after do thing like that.

```
#ifndef TEST
    qDebug() << "test";
#endif
```

Comment: I tried just now, but no difference. It passes this macro to preprocessor just the way DEFINES do. I see it in compilation output. though thanx for try

Comment: or else you can just do #ifndef TEST
    qDebug() << "test";
#endif for each qdebug you want to remove with your macro

Comment: that is not an option. I have to spend hours or days of work to change that.

Comment: as it's a qmake macro I don't think you can do it. this macro will be use to change the makefile not each file I think

Answer (score 0):

As Gabriel de Grimouard pointed out, the `QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT` takes affect when you compile Qt, not your application (as far as I understand).

The only option is to change your code, there are a few options:

1. Do as suggested in his answer, make use of a Macro check before each debug
2. Define your own debug macro that you can enable or disable:

   ```
   // Top of testone.cpp
   #ifdef NO_DEBUG_ONE
     #define DEBUG_MESSAGE(message) 
   #else
     #define DEBUG_MESSAGE(message) qDebug() << message
   #endif
   // In your code
   DEBUG_MESSAGE("This is my debug message");
   ```

   - The benefit of this is that you do not have `#ifndef TEST` everywhere in your code.
3. Make use of the Logging Categories in Qt (recommended)

   - http://blog.qt.io/blog/2014/03/11/qt-weekly-1-categorized-logging/
   - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GDtrbIs6JA0

Unfortunately all of these will require  code changes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but please see Simon answer. It is possible